# Data JPA Test with reactive spring

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-webflux

I want to test the repository layer and I'm using spring webflux. My test class is as follows

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class DataTester {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    .....

}
```

Even though this would work in spring-mvc when using spring-weblux I get the following error.

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...

Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ReactiveWebApplicationContext due to missing ReactiveWebServerFactory bean.
```

How to resolve this? If I am to start the whole application context with `@SpringBootApplication` it works. Any other options without using that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this was that in the `application.properties` the application type was set as reactive.

`spring.main.web-application-type=reactive`

This tries to auto configure a web server in this case a reactive web server. As `@DataJpaTest` does not provide a bean for that, this fails. This can be fixed in either two ways.

One is by Adding an `application.properties` file in the resources directory of the test package and setting the value as,`sprig.main-web-application-type=none` solves this issue.

Or we can simple pass a property value to the annotation as follows. `@DataJpaTest(properties = "spring.main.web-application-type=none")`

Comment: Had exactly the same issue with @DataMongoTest

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot 2+ then only @DataJpaTest is enough on test class.
So your test class should be

```
@DataJpaTest
public class DataTester {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    .....

}
```

Comment: this gives a null pointer exception as repository is not autowired

Comment: then there has to be other issues in your application @Yomal because the documentations clearly states that you only need `@DataJpaTest` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test

Comment: i am using junit 4. Excluding `@Runwith` or `@Extendwith` is only possible with Junit5

Comment: @Yomal which spring boot version are you using ?

Comment: Springboot version 2.2.5